# External Data Column no sorting by a string based additional field

Tags: bcs, external-data-column

Can anyone confirm or tell me why you can't sort by an External Data column additional field if its type descriptor is a `string`?

It works for `int`, `bool` and `guid` type descriptors. If I add a standard 'Single line of text' column it can be sorted.